# Django efficiency: ManyToManyField

Tags: django

In Django, suppose I have a function that is called very often:

```
def blockUser(id_to_block, user):
   to_block = Usr.objects.get(pk=id_to_block)
   user.blocked.add(to_block)
   user.save()
```

Where `user` is of type `Usr`, a custom class made with models.Model and `blocked` is a ManyToManyField.

Now the way I read it, Django will fetch `to_block` from the DB, then add `to_block` to `user.blocked`, accessing the DB twice. Since a ManyToManyField is only a table with `from_id` and `to_id` and that I already know the two ids, could I accomplish it with only one DB access?

My question is, will Django indeed make two DB queries for this, given the fact that `to_block` is not used anywhere else? If so, how could I achieve this with one DB query?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). From the docs:

> This is a performance booster which results in (sometimes much) larger
>   queries but means later use of foreign-key relationships **won’t
>   require database queries**.

#### UPDATE

With a ManyToMany field use [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). Same principal as `select_related()`. From the docs:

> This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which
>   cannot be done using select_related, in addition to the foreign key
>   and one-to-one relationships that are supported by select_related.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think it doesn't work on ManyToMany but only on ForeignKey and OneToOne, as said in the docs `You can refer to any ForeignKey or OneToOneField relation in the list of fields passed to select_related().` and here: http://timmyomahony.com/blog/misconceptions-select_related-in-django/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to fetch the to_block object in order to add it to the blocked ManyToManyField. Using the primary-key works too.
Additionally you don't need to call the save on the user object after adding a relation.

```
def blockUser(id_to_block, user):
   user.blocked.add(id_to_block)
```

Nevertheless this does 2 sql queries.

- First it checks if the user has already blocked the to_block user.
- Afterwards it does the actual insert.

If you want to avoid the check for integrity you can create an instance of the intermediate model directly.

```
def blockUser(id_to_block, user):
    # create an instance of the intermediate model
    block_entry = Usr.blocked.through(user_id=user.id, blocked_id=id_to_block)    
    try:
        with transaction.commit_on_success():
            block_entry.save()
    except IntegrityError:
        pass
```

The `blocked_id` might not be the correct field_name.